# Sweating on Somebody: meaning?

Tags: meaning

I listen to my fair share of Hip-Hop but I'm still not sure what * exactly* it means for a guy to be " sweating" on a girl or vice-versa.

I had a look on Urban Dictionary but couldn't really find anything that fits.

So what does it mean to be "sweating" on someone?

Comment: Do you have any context? I would assume that it means having a crush on somebody, being infatuated, caring, falling in love, etc. You might consider looking the specific song up on rapgenius.com though.

Comment: It's probably an extension from *to sweat [on something] = to **worry** [about it]*. As applied to a guy and a girl, that he *cares* about here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Agreed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this list of slang usages](http://www.tnellen.com/cybereng/slang/discussion.html)...

> **Sweating** - constantly after a girl or boy you want and making it extremely 
>   obvious.
>    *(stop sweating her already damn)*

I think I can safely say the usage isn't particularly common with this *specific* sense. But it's easy enough to see how it would arise from...

> [**sweat**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sweat)
>    5. Informal  a.) To work long and hard. b.) To suffer much, as for a misdeed.
>    6. Informal To fret or worry.
>    10. Informal To fret or worry about: *Don't sweat the details.*

Comment: Quick add: There's a connotation to "sweating on" that also implies uncomfortable closeness.

Answer (score 1):

I would understand 'sweating on someone' to mean that one is literally perspiring on another; it certainly doesn't have any commonly understood idiomatic meaning  that I'm aware of. If you're looking for meaning beyond the literal interpretation than you would need to provide a quote, or some other type of context from which we could derive additional meaning.

Answer (score 1):

To drip sweat on them, perhaps.

I jest. It means that the person is 'hot' for the woman - sexually aroused by them. In this case, they happen to be so 'hot' (sexually) on the person that the metaphor is extended to say that they are dripping sweat (figuratively).